# RidgeClassifier: interpret answers of model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've trained the model and I can't interpret answers in some cases.

I've created toy train sample

```
CourtIDGAS    Addr_upd
03MS0001      usa, new-york, times square, 1
03MS0001      usa, new-york, times square, 3
03MS0001      usa, new-york, times square, 5
03MS0001      usa, new-york, times square, 7
03MS0001      usa, new-york, times square, 9
03MS0001      usa, new-york, times square, 2
03MS0001      usa, new-york, times square, 4
03MS0001      usa, new-york, times square, 6
03MS0001      usa, new-york, times square, 8
03MS0001      usa, new-york, times square, 10
03MS0001      usa, new-york, times square, 12
03MS0002      usa, new-york, times square, 11
03MS0002      usa, new-york, times square, 13
03MS0002      usa, new-york, times square, 14
03MS0002      usa, new-york, times square, 16
```

I use `CountVectorizer` to convert text to vector and use `RidgeClassifier` to predict the class of address.

```
vec = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\\b[а-яё0-9\/\-]+\\b', min_df=1)
X = vec.fit_transform(df.Addr_upd)
Y = df["CourtIDGAS"]
clf = RidgeClassifier(random_state=42)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

And when try predict smth from train sample, I get correct answers
But When I try to predict with another data, for example `usa, new-york, times square, 18`, I get class `03MS0001`.

And I can't interpret this, because the max number in vocabulary it's 16, But this example is closer to `03MS0002` in my mind.

How to interpret answer of this classifier? 
And What's the correct way to working with this data like this?

Comment: Can be overfitting, or a bug in your code. you need to give more info. How much examples did you train your model on ? how much test examples did you use to evaluate the accuracy ? Did you try to use other metrics like AUC or F-measure ? Also can you update the post with all the code you used ?

Comment: `min_df=1` does not make any sense. See the vocabulary from `vec.get_feature_names()`. Single digit numbers will not be there. And other numbers are treated as words, not numbers, so the model dont know that 18 is between 17 and 19 and so on. Since 18 is not in the vocabulary, it will be ignored and predictions will be done only based on other words. Hence the first class as output.